# Override Mui theme nested in theme.breakpoints.up("md")

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**Code**

```
MuiTab: {
    root: {
        height: 140,
        [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
             minWidth: 72,
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

> [ts] Cannot find name 'theme'.

**Problem**

I don't know where to declare "theme".

Answer (score 5):

The snippet you posted probably comes from a method where you create your custom theme by calling `createMuiTheme()`. The trick is to assign the result of `createMuiTheme()` to a local variable and then set the overrides. Then you can use the breakpoints:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import { orange } from 'material-ui/colors';

export function getCustomTheme() {
    let theme: any = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            primary: orange,
        },
        overrides: {}
    });

    theme.overrides.MuiTab = {
        root: {
            height: 140,
            [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
                minWidth: 72,
                backgroundColor: 'red'
            }
        }
    };

    return theme;
}
```